# Selenium throwing null pointer for wait.until

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Trying to automate a page in salesforce, seeing weird issue when trying to wait for an element.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[@title='console']")
private WebElement consoleTitle;

public void switchApplicationLightening(String applicationName) throws InterruptedException {
    String st = util.driver.getPageSource(); //This step to debug I am seeing null here
    String str = util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='console']")).getText(); // This step is not required but added to debug and this is working fine
     if(!verifyElementVisible(consoleTitle, 5)){ //Its failing here and seeing issue
        switchToApplication(applicationName);
    }
}

public static Boolean verifyElementVisible(WebElement element, int explicitWait) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(util.driver, explicitWait);
    System.out.println(util.driver);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | NoSuchFrameException | NoSuchWindowException | ErrorHandler.UnknownServerException | TimeoutException e) {
        VERIFICATION_ERRORS.append("Element: ").append(element).append(" is not present on page \n -Caugth exception: ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n\n");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Seeing below error on step - `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:301)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:298)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)
```

It looks like its not liking wait.until - every time when this is called its throwing null pointer

PS: Please ignore String str = util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='console']")).getText(); this I put for debug illogical as we are waiting for same element below. Also getPageSource() is null but I next step is executed.

Comment: Further debug I found wait.until is waiting if element is not present on the page and throwing error something like below:org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //span[@title='con']' (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at                  Above I gave xpath deliberately wrong. When xpath is right I am seeing null pointer exception.

Comment: Did you initialize Page Factory?

Comment: Yes I did initialize Page Factory. Further debug I found the issue is with ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element) instead if I usenExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated its working. So some issue with visibilityOf

Comment: Presence and visibility are two different things

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@FindBy` you must initialize webElements using `PageFactory.initElements()`.

```
public void switchApplicationLightening(String applicationName) throws InterruptedException {
    PageFactory.initElements(util.driver, this);
    String st = util.driver.getPageSource(); //This step to debug I am seeing null here
    String str = util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='console']")).getText(); // This step is not required but added to debug and this is working fine
     if(!verifyElementVisible(consoleTitle, 5)){ //Its failing here and seeing issue
        switchToApplication(applicationName);
    }
}
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
```

Comment: OP stated in the comment that he initialized Page Factory

Comment: Thanks the confirmed

Answer (score 0):

I think from the code element is passed as null to this method, check how you are calling this.
I see you have consoleTitle, but you never assigned any value to that variable. I think you should assign consoleTitle = str or use str instead.

Comment: I printed element and see this result: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (3d78cf21f32f647c41339ec65d2fd92f)] -> xpath: //span[@title='8x8 Service Console']] So no issues with element. consoleTitle has xpath value. I didn't get why I have to assign str to it?

Comment: I am using str or st above just to debug and see what is the value - those 2 lines are no use for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Conferred with selenium devs on their slack channel.  It was resolved when I upgraded to chrome 78 and the latest chromedriver.  The waits are working again with PageFactory.  there was a critical issue in chrome 77 that caused NPE's.